# Why snapping doesn't work on Leaflet version 1.0.0 and newer?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

On documentation of Leaflet.Draw, Snapping sample is not working with Leaflet 1.0 but it works with Leaflet 0.7

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-polyline

Is it supposed to be works with different method?

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet-Geoman has snapping features for Leaflet 1.0 and above.
https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Leaflet-Geoman